# How to implement limit with Nhibernate and Sybase

Tags: nhibernate, limit, linq-to-nhibernate, sap-ase

We use Nhibernate 3.3 to connect to our Sybase Ase 15 database. Everything is fine except for the non support of the limit (or top). It is implemented in sybase but not in Nhibernate.
Do you have a solution?

I tried to create a CustomSybaseAse15Dialect where I change this:

```
     public override bool SupportsLimitOffset
{
    get { return true; }
}

public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString sql, SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
{    
    int insertionPoint = GetAfterSelectInsertPoint(sql);

    if (insertionPoint > 0)
    {
        SqlStringBuilder limitBuilder = new SqlStringBuilder();
        limitBuilder.Add("select");
        if (insertionPoint > 6)
        {
            limitBuilder.Add(" distinct ");
        }
        limitBuilder.Add(" top ");
        limitBuilder.Add(limit);
        if (offset != null)
        {
            limitBuilder.Add(" start at ");
            limitBuilder.Add(offset);
        }
        limitBuilder.Add(sql.Substring(insertionPoint));
        return limitBuilder.ToSqlString();
    }
    else
    {
        return sql; // unchanged
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Copied from MsSql2000Dialect.
/// </summary>
private int GetAfterSelectInsertPoint(SqlString sql)
{
    if (sql.StartsWithCaseInsensitive("select distinct"))
    {
        return 15;
    }
    if (sql.StartsWithCaseInsensitive("select"))
    {
        return 6;
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException("The query should start with 'SELECT' or 'SELECT DISTINCT'");
}
```

Using the Linq2Nhibernate syntax, it works good with

```
Session.Query<product>().First()
```

limit is correctly set to 1 but if I do this

```
Session.Query<product>().Take(3).ToList()
```

limit is set to "?".

What can I do?

Comment: There seems to be an issue within nHibernate. Did you check https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nhibernate-development/TZVi8ce_Vfo

Comment: Correct! I focused on the problem with sybase but i think you're right. Do you know how I can get the binaries with the corrections or a possible workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the previous comment there is a bug in nHibernate. It is already fixed but not yet included in an official version.

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3281

You can download the main source and build the dll manually from https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core .

Michael

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question recently:

This is fixed in the release version of nHibernate 4.1.

You also need to add to the dialect:

```
public override bool SupportsVariableLimit { get { return false; } }
```

to address the lack of support for placeholders in "select top X" (it defaults to whatever SupportsLimit is)