# NHibernate custom dialect for sybase to support limits

Tags: nhibernate, limit, sybase, linq-to-nhibernate, dialect

I'm using Linq2NHibernate 3.0 with sybase ASE 15.
My first problem was that the dialect does not support limits ("select **top** 5 ..."). As a consequence, I made a custom dialect overriding those methods :

```
public override bool SupportsLimit
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool SupportsLimitOffset
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool SupportsVariableLimit
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public new int GetLimitValue(int offset, int limit)
    {
          //TOOK FROM ANOTHER DIALECT
        if (limit == int.MaxValue)
            return int.MaxValue;

        if (UseMaxForLimit)
            return GetOffsetValue(offset) + limit;

        return limit;

    }

    public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString sql, SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
    {
        //TOOK FROM ANOTHER DIALECT EXCEPT THAT I CALL ANOTHER CUSTOM CLASS
    }
```

NOTE : I USE ANOTHER CLASS TO PASS THE LIMIT VALUE INTO GetLimitString USING LOCKS (I did not find a better alternative)

I thought it worked fine but GetLimitString is only called once, as a result, if I change the limit value, it is not taken into account.

So, my problem can be solved two ways: you have a better custom dialect for Sybase, or you know why GetLimitString is only called once.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be stupid comment, but have you traced your code to ensure that GetLimitString is only called once, and it is not the mechanism you used to inject the limit which always returns the same result ?

Comment: Yes, even in debugging, it's only called once.

Comment: Just a related note as I ran into this issue: Sybase ASE doesn't support TOP on sub-selects, so the above generates invalid SQL in that case. 

There's no method to distinguish between selects and sub-selects with the current nhibernate API. (Other than looking at the callstack).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478699/how-to-implement-limit-with-nhibernate-and-sybase has a working solution.